# Sudden error in SQL criteria

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I was using the following SQL - This worked fine

```
Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Count(Advisors) AS TotalNumber FROM tbl_ComplaintsCoded WHERE Advisors = '" & Forms!frm_Central_Reporting_ops!Text52.Value & "' AND Year([Mail Date]) = " & Me.Text48.Value & " AND month([Mail Date]) =4")
```

I have made a slight change to:

```
Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Count(PolicyComplaints) AS TotalNumber FROM tbl_ComplaintsCoded WHERE PolicyComplaints = '" & Forms!frm_Central_Reporting_ops!Text52.Value & "' AND Year([Mail Date]) = " & Me.Text48.Value & " AND month([Mail Date]) =4")
```

The error is:

> Data type mismatch in expression

I cant work out at all what has gone so drastically wrong?

Help

Comment: Which datatype is the field PolicyComplaints ?

Comment: Probably it's not a alphanumeric datatype. Try to delete the ' Char:

    WHERE PolicyComplaints = " & Forms!frm_Central_Reporting_ops!Text52.Value & " AND Year

Comment: To do a count without the criteria?

Comment: That actually worked and done a count. How would I add in the multi criteria, from the one I already had?

Comment: Sorry I don't get your question. Please paste your code

Comment: Apologies - This is what I have no: Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Count(PolicyComplaints) AS TotalNumber FROM tbl_ComplaintsCoded")

Comment: Try `Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Count(PolicyComplaints) AS TotalNumber FROM tbl_ComplaintsCoded WHERE PolicyComplaints = " & Forms!frm_Central_Reporting_ops!Text52.Value & " AND Year([Mail Date]) = " & Me.Text48.Value & " AND month([Mail Date]) =4")`

Comment: Thanks, apologies this is taking longer than expected. That throws our a missing operator error

Comment: It is amazing how much easier life gets with parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot surround calculated field with single quotation marks. Remove the quotation marks and it should work. Here is an example:

```
Private Sub showQueryData()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim sqlStr As String

sqlStr = "SELECT COUNT(CalculatedField) AS TotalNumber FROM table1 AS tbl WHERE CalculatedField = '2'"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sqlStr)

Dim result As String
result = rs!TotalNumber

End Sub
```

above method will error out due to query parameter '2'. It will work when you remove quotations as below:

```
Private Sub showQueryData()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim sqlStr As String

sqlStr = "SELECT COUNT(CalculatedField) AS TotalNumber FROM table1 AS tbl WHERE CalculatedField = 2"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sqlStr)

Dim result As String
result = rs!TotalNumber

End Sub
```

I have rewritten your code without surrounding quotations which works in my end:

```
Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Count(PolicyComplaints) AS TotalNumber FROM tbl_ComplaintsCoded WHERE PolicyComplaints = " & Forms!frm_Central_Reporting_ops!Text52.Value & " AND Year([Mail Date]) = " & Me.Text48.Value & " AND month([Mail Date]) =4")
```